# Populate vector with protobuf objects in the constructor

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Is there a 1-line way to do that directly via the vector constructor?

```
std::vector<someproto> vector_protos;
vector_protos.emplace_back();
```

Something like `vector_protos(1)`.

Comment: Did you not try `std::vector<someproto> vector_protos(1);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), that accepts `count` - i.e. number of elements (see item **(4)** in the link):

> (4) Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T.
> No copies are made.

To construct `vector_protos` with 1 default contructed element you can use:

```
std::vector<someproto> vector_protos(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<someproto> vector_protos = {someproto(), someproto()};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.